# Advanced groupby column creation in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I have a catalogue of groups of galaxies in a DataFrame, `'compact'`, which consists mainly in

- a group id (`'CG'`, int),
- a magnitude (`'R'`, negative float)
- and a morphology (`'Morph'`, string, for example 'S' or 'E').

I'm trying to construct a second pandas DataFrame with the following properties of the groups:

- `'Morph'` of the object having the lowest `'R'` in the group
- Difference between the second lowest and the lowest `'R'` in the group
- Difference between the lowest `'R'` in the group and R of the group, defined as `-2.5*log10(sum(10**(-0.4*R)))`
- Proportions of objects having a given `'Morph'` (on column for 'S', one for other morphologies, for example) in the group, NOT COUNTING THE ONE HAVING THE LOWEST `'R'`.

I'm having troubles for the last one, could you help me to write it? The other ones work, but, as a secondary question, I would like if I'm doing it clean or if there's better to do.

Here is my code (with a line for my last column which works but doesn't give exactly what I want, and a try in comments which doesn't work):

```
GroupBy = compact.sort_values('R').groupby('CG', as_index=False)
R2 = GroupBy.head(2).groupby('CG', as_index=False).last().R
R1 = GroupBy.first().sort_values('CG').R
DeltaR12 =  R2 - R1 
MorphCen = GroupBy.first().sort_values('CG').Morph
Group = GroupBy.first().sort_values('CG').CG
RGroup = GroupBy.apply(lambda x: -2.5*np.log10((10**(-0.4*x.R)).sum()))
DeltaR1gr = R1 - RGroup


# Works, but counts the object with lowest R:
PropS = GroupBy.apply(lambda x: 1.0*x.loc[x['Morph'] == 'S'].shape[0]/x.shape[0])   
# Tries to let aside lowest R, but doesn't work:
# PropS = GroupBy.apply(lambda x: 1.0*x.loc[x['Morph'] == 'S' & 
#                        x['R']>x['R'].min()].shape[0]/x.shape[0])

# PropRed = same than PropS, but for 'Morph' != 'S'

CompactML = pd.DataFrame([Group,MorphCen,DeltaR12,DeltaR1gr]).transpose()
CompactML.columns = ['CG', 'MorphCen', 'DeltaR12','DeltaR1gr']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is the final code, thanks to [Ted Pertou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3707607/ted-petrou):

```
# define custom aggregation function
def my_agg(x):
    x = x.sort_values('R')
    morph = x.head(1)['Morph'].values[0]
    diff = x.iloc[1]['R'] - x.iloc[0]['R']
    diff2 =  x.iloc[0]['R'] + 2.5*np.log10(sum(10**(-0.4*x['R'])))
    prop = (x['Morph'].iloc[1:] == 'S').mean()
    return pd.Series([morph, diff, diff2, prop], index=['MorphCen', 'DeltaR12', 'DeltaRGrp1', 'PropS'])

# apply custom agg function
compact.groupby('CG').apply(my_agg)
```

Answer (score 3):

First, its nice if you provide actual data or create some fake data. Below I have created some fake data with 5 different integer CG groups, 2 types of morphology (S and E) and random negative numbers for 'R'.

I have then redone all your aggregations in a custom function that computes each of the 4 returning aggregations in one line and sends the results back as a Series which adds each output as row to your original DataFrame.

```
#create fake data
df = pd.DataFrame({'CG':np.random.randint(0, 5, 100), 'Morph':np.random.choice(['S', 'E'], 100), 'R':np.random.rand(100) * -100})
print(df.head())

   CG Morph          R
0   3     E -72.377887
1   2     E -26.126565
2   0     E  -4.428494
3   0     E  -2.055434
4   4     E -93.341489

# define custom aggregation function
def my_agg(x):
    x = x.sort_values('R')
    morph = x.head(1)['Morph'].values[0]
    diff = x.iloc[0]['R'] - x.iloc[1]['R']
    diff2 = -2.5*np.log10(sum(10**(-0.4*x['R'])))
    prop = (x['Morph'].iloc[1:] == 'S').mean()
    return pd.Series([morph, diff, diff2, prop], index=['morph', 'diff', 'diff2', 'prop'])

# apply custom agg function
df.groupby('CG').apply(my_agg)

   morph       diff      diff2      prop
CG                                      
0      E  -1.562630 -97.676934  0.555556
1      S  -3.228845 -98.398337  0.391304
2      S  -6.537937 -91.092164  0.307692
3      E  -0.023813 -99.919336  0.500000
4      E -11.943842 -99.815734  0.705882
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand how it works! :) Sorry for mock data, I'll provide it next time.

Comment: The major part of your code works fine. Only `diff` is wrong for me, and in your example too. I'm trying to figure out what's going on. Thanks again!

Comment: OK, I see. I post the proper code and I accept your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: It was wrong. Just subtract the first two values. I made the edit in the code

Comment: Yes, thank you. I had already posted it when I saw your comment.

Comment: Just one thing: do you know why `CG`is not a label anymore?

Comment: The grouping columns always become the index. Use `df.reset_index()`

Comment: Great! Works perfectly. Thank you very much!